# PowerShell module ImportExcel only returning up to column AF2 when many other columns available to the right of AF2

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-module

I am using the PowerShell module `ImportExcel` from here: https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel

To eliminate my complex code I am just running the following: *(xxx indicates folders I dont want to show)*

```
$ExcelFilePath = "C:\Users\<xxx>\code\<xxx>\<xxx>\AllSqlServersV2.xlsx"
$Excel = Open-ExcelPackage -Path $ExcelFilePath
$Excel.Recommended_for_instances.Dimension
```

And here is the output for `$Excel.Recommended_for_instances.Dimension`:

```
Start   : OfficeOpenXml.ExcelCellAddress
End     : OfficeOpenXml.ExcelCellAddress
Table   : 
Address : A1:AF2 <=== 
IsName  : False
Rows    : 2
Columns : 32 <===
```

And here is a screen shot of the data. You will see a vertical red line after column `AF` to show that I can get any data after this point. *(sorry for the very wide picture)*

All the data:
[image]

A snapshot of the data point that I am having issues getting past:
[image]

As you can see, I am not doing anything out of the ordinary.
The interesting thing is, if I open the Excel file, press `ctrl s` only *(save the file without making any changes)* then the output of the above code becomes correct:

```
Start   : OfficeOpenXml.ExcelCellAddress
End     : OfficeOpenXml.ExcelCellAddress
Table   : 
Address : A1:BA2 <=== ✅
IsName  : False
Rows    : 2
Columns : 53 <=== ✅
```

I have looked for a reason for this all day but can't find anything useful.

Any help would be great.

cheers

Russ

Comment: A stab in the dark. If you open the file, press Alt+F11 to open the VB editor, and in the Immediate Window enter `? ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address`, what is the result?

Comment: Sounds like the kind of thing you should create a bug for at their github site: https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/issues/new

Comment: How are you creating the original excel file? It *sounds* like there’s some sort of internal inconsistency in the file that Excel is fixing when it re-saves. Are you able to see what changes are made if you unzip the “before” and “after” xlsx files and compare the folder / file contents?

Comment: @BigBen I tried what you said. Note that I had to click the "Enable Editing" button in Excel first. The results of "? ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address" was:
$A$1:$BA$2 ✅
Which is my desired result but not what I get from code as mentioned in my question.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician thanks I have submitted an issue as you suggested:
https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/issues/1432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've compared your original spreadsheet file in the GitHub issue versus the one re-saved by Excel and it looks like there's a couple of parts that Excel saves differently to whatever tool you used to generate the original file.

These differences alter how [EPPlus](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus) (the underlying library used by `ImportExcel`) processes the file, which at least *explains* the different results you're seeing in the `Dimension` property in ImportExcel.

Here's some screenshots from BeyondCompare comparing the unzipped original file and the one saved in Excel:

[image]

Some things to note:

- Your original "broken" file is on the left, the one saved by Excel is on the right
- The Excel file has a "dimension" element, although as far as I can tell, EPPlus doesnt actually read this, and calculates the `Dimension` dynamically from the column and cell data in the rest of the worksheet xml.
- The original file has multiple `<cols><col>...</col></cols>` with just one `<col>` per `<cols>`, whereas the Excel version has all of the `<col>` elements in a single `<cols>` - it turns out EPPlus only reads the first `<cols>` element (see [ExcelWorksheet.cs#L1439](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/blob/77a102acf0108ab81c8538ce378258850c8688e5/src/EPPlus/ExcelWorksheet.cs#L1439)) which it uses to calculate used range / Dimension. (I'm not sure if the OpenXml spec allows multiple `<cols>` elements, so this could be a bug in whatever you used to generate the file, *or* a compatibility issue in EPPlus.

There's some additional differences further down the file:

[image]

- For columns `A1`-`AF1`, the original file serialises them as, e.g. `<c r="AF1" s="1" t="n">`, but from `AG1` onwards it serialises as `r="nnn"` - e.g. `<c r="322" s="1" t="n">` - EPPlus fails to parse these [here](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/blob/77a102acf0108ab81c8538ce378258850c8688e5/src/EPPlus/ExcelWorksheet.cs#L1716) and so doesn't expand the `Dimension` property to include the columns. By contrast, Excel saves them as `<c r="AG2" s="1">` which EPPlus reads find and expands the range to include these columns..
- I'm not sure if *this* is a bug in your original file, or again a compatiblity issue in EPPlus.

### Summary

There's a couple of things Excel saves differently compared to your original file that mean EPPlus can process the saved file correctly, and this surfaces up in the `Dimension` property `ImportExcel` module.

Maybe these differences are allowed in older / newer versions of the OpenXML spec, or maybe Excel has some additional error handling for reading and correcting some common errors in files, but as it stands, EPPlus (and vicariously, ImportExcel) doesn't like the files generated by your application :-(

Comment: thanks so much for this long and detailed response. I didn't think to use Beyond compare and tried to compare with FC.exe which was crap. Ok, I will go back to my team and Microsoft who generated the file directly in Azure and figure out a plan for going forward. Again, thanks so much for this, can I buy you a beer?

Comment: Np, yw. And offer appreciated, but not required - I enjoy the problem-solving on some of these questions :-). Feel free to make a small donation to your favourite good cause in lieu though if you like though... M

Comment: Might be worth pinging an update in your GitHub ticket as well - the owner can review whether it's something they want to investigate further or not...

Comment: good idea, I will update... cheers