Formula in last row of xlsx not parsed in Powershell
I am downloading an xlsx file linked to a MS Form (so each new row is a new form submission) from Sharepoint and importing it in Powershell via ImportExcel module
$f = Import-Excel -Path "$path" -WorksheetName "Foglio1"
The excel has a SCRIPT column with a custom formula, that references values submitted in the form, something like this:
=CONCAT(H1438,"/",IF(I1438="LOST","LE","AM"),"/",K1438,IF(V1438="Yes",CONCAT("job-",W1438),""))
All rows are imported fine in powershell, except the last one, in which the formula is not parsed. In excel however the last row has all the values submitted and the correct formula.

Last two rows of the xlsx file imported in PS. I redacted sensitive data from SCRIPT column, but you can see the difference with le last column

Last two rows in Excel
I tried:

changing the formula (column "Select a COUNTRY16"), but same behaviour.
imported the downloaded xlsx file in R with R Studio, same issue on the last row

I also noticed that

if I open the file in Excel and make any edit on the last row (delete a value and write it back in), when I download it again and import it in Powershell, the last row is parsed correctly.


https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/issues is also a good place for ImportExcel questions.

yes but I have the same behavior when reading the same file with another language (R) so I don't think the issue is with the PS module

Excel is more tolerant of some inconsistencies / errors / corruptions in excel workbook files than other tools are - see this q&a for a similar issue with ImportExcel not reading past a certain column (rather than row) - the symptom of "saving in excel and then processing" sounds like a similar issue at least, where saving the file in Excel fixes the inconsistencies in the workbook and allows other tools to process the complete file... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75943288/powershell-module-importexcel-only-returning-up-to-column-af2-when-many-other-co/75948801#75948801
